# Create REST API without using any backend

Tags: json, rest, api, backend, static-site

How do you create a rest api without using any backend technologies such as node, express? ie: Is it possible to create an api using only client side framework such as react, vue and no server side involved?

I would like to create a very simple rest api which I can host either on github pages or gitlab pages.

I would like a live rest api that I can access via my own domain such as http://username.github.io and not a fake one that you can create using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) or [My JSON Server](https://my-json-server.typicode.com) - and would be able to do the following.

**Here is the description of what the api should do.**

> /quotes.txt - Read the contents of the quotes.txt file and display it
>
> /quotes.json - Read the contents of the quotes.txt file and convert it
>   to json format
>
> /random.txt - Read the contents of the quotes.txt file and display a
>   random quote in txt format
>
> /random.json - Read the contents of the quotes.txt file and display a
>   random quote in json format

**Output of the API**

/quotes.txt

```
To be or not to be that is the question - Author Unknown
All your dreams can come true if you have the courage to pursue them - Walt Disney
Stand up for what you believe in even if you are standing alone -
```

/quotes.json

```
[
  {
    "quote": "To be or not to be that is the question",
    "author": "Author Unknown"
  },
  {
    "quote": "All your dreams can come true if you have the courage to pursue them",
    "author": "Walt Disney"
  },
  {
    "quote": "Stand up for what you believe in even if you are standing alone",
    "author": ""
  }
]
```

/random.txt

```
All your dreams can come true if you have the courage to pursue them - Walt Disney
```

/random.json

```
  {
    "quote": "All your dreams can come true if you have the courage to pursue them",
    "author": "Walt Disney"
  }
```

Comment: Without Backend, Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to serve a JSON file. It supports "canonic" ways to express RESTful requests. This tool can be used on a dev machine or on a intranet server. Here's a [blog post](https://scotch.io/tutorials/json-server-as-a-fake-rest-api-in-frontend-development) about how to set it up.

[My JSON Server](https://my-json-server.typicode.com) is a service that does the same exact thing in the Internet environment for you. There are also competing services with similar functionalities, e.g. [myjson.com](http://myjson.com). I'm sure you will find more if you search online.

---

**P.S. I'm sure you'll need to do some massaging to actually translate `.txt` -> `.json`. I've never seen services that work against `.txt` files rather than `.json` ones.**

Ugh. I really like question edits that invalidate the answers.